# Pycharm Inline documentation not working for python 3.7 in Macbook

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm in Macbook.

In Python version 3.6 as project interpreter, i am able to see inline documentation by pressing F1. It works perfectly.

However if I choose 3.7 as project interpreter, I am not able to see complete inline documentation. The information like example usage, parameter, etc., is missing from the documentation.

Any help how to make it work?

Comment: btw you can also open & attach a ticket from PyCharm bugtracker

Comment: Shortcut for documentation is `Ctrl + Q` when you place your cursor on class or module or function. Shouldn't you use `Ctrl + Q` ?